# Grep only exact last 4 digits from Number file

Tags: grep

Grep only exact last 4 digits from Number file.

```
$ cat test
12298700077
56198700770
23192604888
34198701041
89198701285
$ cat test | grep 0077
12298700077
56198700770
```

Required output is just this

```
12298700077
```

Comment: what did you try yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex and especially (`man 7 regex`): *'$' (matching the null string at the end of a line)*:

```
$ grep 0077$ file
12298700077
```